# Strassen's algorithm on unit vectors?

Tags: optimization, matrices, linear-algebra

I am trying to do a dot product of two vectors of each 128 dimension. I am just looping each member and calculating the sum.

```
public Double dotProduct(List<Double> v, List<Double> u) {
    Double dotProduct = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 128; i++) {
        dotProduct += v.get(i) * u.get(i);
    }
    return dotProduct;
}
```

Will strassen's algorithm perform better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strassen's algorithm is for multiplying square matrices, not vectors. Your algorithm already runs in (asymptotically) optimal time $O(n)$ (where $n$ is the dimension of the vector), and also uses the optimal number of multiplications.